# Checking requesting script url in SOAP

Tags: php, soap

I have very basic SOAP server:

```
$soap = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => ''));

$soap->addFunction('myFunction');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $soap->handle();
} else {
    echo "Available functions:";
    foreach ($soap->getFunctions() as $func) {
        echo "\n\t" . $func;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a specific set of domains (that I own) from which I expect requests, and no others - say in the array:

```
$allowed_domains = array('http://www.example.com', 'http://www.otherexample.com');
```

How could I create a 'whitelist', as in only those domains can actually make a request to this soap server script (any others will be denied access)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The check can be as follow :

```
if(!in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $allowed_domains) {
    // operation is denied
    exit 0;
}
```

Hope That Helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! Unfortunately, `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` isn't set...

Comment: Try with gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) instead of $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't actually return the requesting domain, but the server owner's domain (which isn't one of mine). I think I'll just do it by requesting username and password instead of the 'whitelist' system.